# Redirect to another page based on form input in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redirect, next.js

I'm just getting started with Next.js and SPA world. I'm used to PHP and plain JS so this is totally new to me.

So I have a form with basically a text input and a submit button. What I need to do is as simple as redirecting the user based on the text field they submit but I can't figure out how.

For example: the form is in the homepage, the user inputs "foo" and submits. What the result should be is that the user is redirected to "/channel/foo".

Any tip? Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok..
For this you can use useRouter hook provided by the nextjs

first you can import it

`import { useRouter } from "next/router";`

then you can create it's instance and use it to push the react app to new route
based on the value of the given form input value

Here I am using a react state to go to new route

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import {useState} from 'react'
export default function SampleComponent(){
    const router = useRouter()
    const [route, setRoute] = useState()
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        router.push("someBasePath/" + route)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Example Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name='route' onChange={(e)=>{setRoute(e.target.value)}} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I hope you are familial with react and useState hook

I hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 8):

You can use useRouter hook to navigate to another page. For example:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Component = () => {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();
  
  const onChange = e => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push(`/channel/${inputValue}`)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input onChange={onChange} />
    </form>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 4):

To handle redirections in Next.js, you can use the router hook `useRouter()` available in any component, with `push`. You can find a good explanation in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router).

Depending on the way you handle your form, you could have a callback on the button, or handle it with the `onSubmit` of the form.

About react forms: [react forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

About handling button click in React: [react buttons](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

make it server side with this trick:

page.tsx(.jsx)

```
<form action="/yourCustomPath">
 <input type="text" name="user-input" />
 <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

in next.js middleware.ts(.js) file

```
export function middleware(request) {
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname === `/yourCustomPath`) {
      const userInput = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("user-input");
      return Response.redirect(new URL(`/yourCustomPath/${userInput}`, request.nextUrl))
    }
}
```